# Stuck at converting unix timestamp string into readable date

Tags: java, android

Trying to convert it into readable date format **as shortly as possible** and got stuck:

```
item.put("date", DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ssaa", jsonChildNode.optString("date") * 1000L));
```

`Error: Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'long'`

Comment: Hahaha.... 3141

Comment: You try to multiply a String Object with a long primitive ... that will not work

Comment: Any shortcut way to get readable date?

Comment: @Fresco please use a long value instead of an integer... Check my answer. Using an integer can potentially have the issue of integer overflow when you multiply it with 1000... My answer gives you an alternative for your approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above is disregarding the fact that it's a Unix timestamp so it'll not fit inside an int value. Also from your question, seems like it's Unix timestamp in seconds instead of milliseconds which the Date class accepts.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/Mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");

long unixTimeInSeconds = jsonChildNode.getLong("date");

item.put("date",sdf.format(new Date(unixTimeInSeconds * 1000L)));


Log.d("tag",sdf.format(new Date(unixTimeInSeconds * 1000L)));
```

Here put everything inside a try catch block as this code can throw exceptions if the timestamp key is not present or has some data which can't be parsed to long

Answer (score 0):

Changed code:

```
int date = Integer.valueOf(jsonChildNode.optString("date"));
item.put("date", DateUtils.formatDateTime(HistoryWithdrawal.this, date, DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE));
```

Comment: It's a date in unix timestamp... It'll be larger than the max values supported by int, use Long please